# Do you need a buffer to get a shiny finish on jewelery?

Tags: jewelry

Having a giant electrical machine just for buffing metal isn't convenient for me. If I could, I would prefer to just sand away. Is it possible to obtain as good of a finish as you would see with a buffer by using continuously less course sand-paper layer by layer?

Comment: Gold dust careful don't breathe. And silver paste

Comment: Wouldn't sandpaper be way too course for jewellery buffing? The coarsest rouge I recall seeing used was still more like clay than sand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, you definitely don't need a buffer

[image: Sutton Hoo belt buckle]
*[Image from Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sutton_Hoo_(3).JPG)*

This gold belt buckle dates from the 6th century - long before buffing machines were invented. Finishing jewellery by hand is the traditional way to do it, and as you can see the results can be excellent.

### However, you can't get this kind of finish just with sandpaper

Going up through the grades of sandpaper is a good way to start, but to achieve a truly smooth finish you need something finer. There are a few different things that are available now for final polishing, but the traditional one is [ferric oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide#Polishing), also known as *jeweller's rouge*.

You can use this by applying a little to a polishing cloth, and polishing the piece until it's done ([you'll need to wipe the rouge off afterwards](https://www.quicktest.co.uk/polishing.htm#rougeforgold))

Answer (score 4):

You could repurpose a carpentry drill, Dremel rotary tool, or even a makeup nail buffer to serve as a small buffer.  Specialty bits are available for carpentry drills and Dremel which have the buffing cloth already attached.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Dremel or Rotron tool with a buffing or polishing wheel mounted will radically shorten the time needed to get a high polish on any surface.

If you mean to limit yourself to non-mechanical methods then jewelers polish, diamond paste, or aluminum oxide pastes are what you need .. applied to a sponge, cloth, or bit of soft leather.